# Show that the set $X= \{\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{4n^2+1}}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded above and that its supremum is $\frac12$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I've been told to say:
Assume that $B<\frac12$ is an upper bound so that $\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{4n^2+1}} \leq B < \frac12$
I need to use contradiction to prove the upper bound is $\frac12$ can anyone help?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: As written the statement is false.  Without parentheses the $n$ is not divided by anything and there is no upper bound.

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: This is *not* a recommended method, but it's fun:
\begin{align*}
\frac{n - 1}{\sqrt{4n^2 + 1}} & =
\frac{n - 1}{2n} - \left(\frac{n - 1}{2n} -
\frac{n - 1}{\sqrt{4n^2 + 1}}\right) \\
& = \frac12 - \frac1{2n} - \frac{(n - 1)(\sqrt{4n^2 + 1} - 2n)}
{2n\sqrt{4n^2 + 1}} \\
& = \frac12 - \frac1{2n} - \frac{(n - 1)}
{2n\sqrt{4n^2 + 1}(\sqrt{4n^2 + 1} + 2n)} \\
& > \frac12 - \frac1{2n} - \frac{n}{(2n)(2n)(2n + 2n)} \\
& = \frac12 - \frac1{2n} - \frac1{16n^2} \\
& > \frac12 - \frac1n \\
& > \frac12 - \epsilon \quad \text{for all } n > \frac1\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: In case it's not clear: @stéphane-jaouen's comment was an important one. Questions are likely to be closed if they do not show work and context, especially if they look like requests for help with homework. There is some introductory material for newcomers, but I'm not sure which is the best text to recommend, so I'll leave it to someone else to do that.

Answer (score 1):

By taking the limit when $n$ approaches infinity you get that if $B$ is an upper bound for the sequence, then necessarily $B\geq \frac{1}{2}$. This follows from the fact $\frac{1}{2}$ is the limit of the sequence, and therefore an accumulation point.

Now assume that there exists some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{4n^2+1}}>\frac{1}{2}.
$$
If you solve the inequality, you will get that $-4n>0$, which is a contradiction for any natural number $n$.

Comment: The argument in the second paragraph is unnecessarily elaborate.  In particular, there is no need to argue by contradiction.  One can argue directly that $n - 1 < n$ and $\sqrt{4n^2 + 1} > 2n,$ which immediately gives
$$
\frac{n - 1}{\sqrt{4n^2 + 1}} < \frac{n}{2n} = \frac12.
$$

Answer (score 0):

u need to prove that $\frac{1}{2}$ is an upper bound and that it is the smallest upper bound,i.e $$\forall \delta >0,\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{4n^2+1}}>\frac{1}{2}-\delta $$.Remark that $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N};\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{4n^2+1}}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}}{2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4n^{2}}}}$$ and $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N};\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4n^{2}}}>1$$ .using thes two remarks ,u would be able to prove the statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, your last inequality goes the wrong way.  But one can argue that
$$
\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac1{4n^2}}\right)^{-1} \! >
\left(1 + \frac1{8n^2}\right)^{-1} > 1 - \frac1{8n^2}.
$$
This leads to the same inequality I found in my comment earlier, by a more sensible route than the one I took.